# reverse string in c++ using char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, char

I tried to reverse a string using char array but in the output it prints some garbage value, I am unaware of that what is the cause plus it is only happening in large strings.

my code

```
string reverseWord(string str){
  int j = 0, n=0;
  
  n = str.length();
  char t[n]={0};
  for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
     t[j]=str[i];
     j+=1;
  }
  return t;
}
```

input = APFGMRZXIFPSXKOQDRRQJBBZ
output = ZBBJQRRDQOKXSPFIXZRMGFPAB@

I want to know the reason behind @ these two garbage values

Using online IDE of gfg.

Comment: `std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); return str;` -- Any reason why you're simply not doing that?

Comment: `char t[n]={0};` is a variable-length array and not supported by standard C++. You should avoid it for portability.

Comment: Where ever you've learned this coding style you should unlearn it AFAIK. You have a unnecessary copy of your function argument. You have unsupported variable-length array. You have legacy C-style strings. You have a unnecessary conversion of the return value. The whole function could be `return string(str.rbegin(), str.rend());`

Answer (score 3):

C-style strings must be terminated by a null-character `'\0'`.

Instead of using Variable-Length Array, which is not in the standard C++, you should directly allocate `string` because you are returning that. (assuming that `string` here means [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string))

```
string reverseWord(string str){
  int j = 0, n=0;
  
  n = str.length();
  string t(n); // allocate string instead of VLA
  for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
     t[j]=str[i];
     j+=1;
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should mention the possibility of simply reversing the string in place in this case to avoid the memory allocation (that or the fact that `string` should better be passed as const reference)...

Comment: input as Geeks the output is skeeG, which is right but causing trouble in the particular type of input as shown above can you please elaborate the cause

Comment: @Arav _"can you please elaborate the cause"_ the cause is _"C-style strings must be terminated by a null-character `'\0'`"_.